# Webcam live streaming in a Java webapp

Tags: java, web-applications, webcam, http-live-streaming

Ok, I know this is probably not so easy but I have this requirement. Basically the webapp will have a simple jsp with a live streaming webcam. How can I get the stream and embed it in the application?

I've read about RTPS and Red5 and stuff like that but seems not so easy to find a simple and clear tutorial on how to do this!

Btw I'm open to evrything else (like http streaming? flash?). The simpler, the better!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you asking how to record the webcam streaming?

Comment: Nope, that's not important. :)